# Solving $a \psi'(\xi) - b \psi (\xi) = c \psi'' (\xi) - \psi''' (\xi)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$a,b,c$ are arbitrary real numbers, more specifically: $a = m_1 m_2 + m_2 m_3 + m_3 m_1$, $b = m_1 m_2 m_3$ and $c = m_1 + m_2 + m_3$ where $m_1, m_2, m_3 \in \mathbb{R}$

**My attempt**

I thought, that I first find out the "general" solution for this ODE i.e. solving

$$a \psi'(\xi) - b \psi(\xi) = 0$$

and solving

$$c\psi''(\xi)-\psi'''(\xi)=0$$

I get:

$$a \psi'(\xi) - b \psi(\xi) = 0$$

$$a \psi'(\xi)=b\psi(\xi)$$

$$\frac{\psi'(\xi)}{\psi(\xi)}=\frac{b}{a}$$

$$\Rightarrow \quad \ln |\psi(\xi)|=\frac{b}{a}\xi + C$$

$$\Rightarrow \quad \psi (\xi)=\tilde{C}e^{\frac{b}{a}\xi}$$

For the second ODE, I get:

$$c \psi''(\xi)-\psi'''(\xi)=0$$

$$c\psi''(\xi)=\psi'''(\xi)$$

$$c = \frac{\psi'''(\xi)}{\psi''(\xi)}$$

$$\Rightarrow \quad c\xi + D= \ln |\psi''(\xi)|$$

$$\Rightarrow \quad \psi''(\xi)=\tilde{D}e^{c\xi}$$

$$\Rightarrow \quad \psi'(\xi) = \tilde{D}_1 e^{c\xi} + \tilde{D}_2$$

$$\Rightarrow \quad \psi(\xi) = \tilde{D}_1^0 e^{c\xi} + \tilde{D}_2^0 \xi + \tilde{D}_3^0$$

---

The problem I have here is that if I use e.g.

$$\psi(\xi)=\tilde{C}(\xi)e^{\frac{b}{a}\xi}$$

and put it into the original ODE, I get a much more complicated ODE than before (checked it with Mathematica)

The same is true if I use the other "general" solution instead.

Can such an approach even work here in the first place?

Comment: This equation is impossible to solve generally without knowing the exact values of $a,b,c$ because the associated polynomial may have repeated roots. Having said that, "guess" a solution of the form $e^{r\xi}$ and plug it into the differential equation to find that polynomial in $r$. Afterwards, you can take all three cases (no repeats, 2 repeated, 3 repeated) and write out their general solutions separately.

Comment: If $b=ca$ then $\sin(\sqrt{a}\xi)$ is a solution for example but it depends on the values of the coefficients.

Comment: @NinadMunshi I just realized that I forgot to tell you what $a,b,c$ are. They are just arbitrary real numbers. You are right about this "guess" approach you're suggesting, because that's what our Prof told us to do, but he asked me to specifically check if my approach would work, too

Comment: @Gauge_name Interesting, but it wouldn't work here, because actually, $a = m_1 m_2 + m_2 m_3 + m_3 m_1$, $b = m_1 m_2 m_3$ and $c = m_1 + m_2 + m_3$ where $m_1, m_2, m_3 \in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: @anon refresh the page and see the extended end of my comment too

Comment: @NinadMunshi Yes, this would be the simplest approach here, you're right. But can I make my approach somehow work? I ask because my Prof asked me to check if my approach could work

Comment: The short answer is no, because when you combine distinct differential equations, their simultaneous solutions are not the only solutions in their new joint solution space. PDE techniques like separation of variables rely on this fact.